# importprivkey in bitgold-cli not importing the expected address

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, bitcoin-gold

I'm in the process of trying to import an existing paper wallet BTC private key into a Bitcoin Gold node I setup so that I can grab the BTG that was airdropped there, however whenever I try to importprivkey the public address associated doesn't match what I had generated, and there are no funds there (they are there if I have the right address in the BTG block chain explorer) I tried:

1. Generating a random new address on bitaddress.org
   `1MiXQPkKZersaFrPmteiUexGbyLEATxD8x / Ky324ikVv9HAjeoz7CVWQN2zA8bVY3aDU1gJq8tJjpEQRmUgJXCK`
2. Importing that address in the cli - `./bgold-cli importprivkey "Ky324ikVv9HAjeoz7CVWQN2zA8bVY3aDU1gJq8tJjpEQRmUgJXCK" "test" true`
3. Get the address for the private key I just imported `bgold-cli getaddressesbyaccount`

I'd expect to get `1MiXQPkKZersaFrPmteiUexGbyLEATxD8x` but instead get:

```
bgold-cli getaddressesbyaccount test
[
  "GeZSpX5GYWUAej9ghqJpuRJAX985Ayn99A"
]
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Why is my public address getting morphed?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Gold uses a different address format than Bitcoin. Even though the private keys can be used across coins, the addresses calculated from them will look different from each other but still encode the same data.